# How to force TRIM on Android device?

Tags: root-access, file-system, performance, lagging, maintenance

With 4.3 enabling the support for TRIM (though I read that it was present since the first JB). I was wondering if there is a way for me to force TRIM on my device? Is there an app that I can sideload and have it issue it? I have a rooted chinese Tablet running on 4.2.2 JellyBean release.

Just to add, it's a PiPo M1 Max tablet.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called [LagFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grilledmonkey.lagfix), which can let you trim your device literally.

It can only run if the device is rooted, and since your device is already rooted then it is perfect for you.

And here is the [thread on Xda developers about LagFix](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2104326).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I used the app, but it is giving me a FS:TRIM Operation not supported on transport endpoint. Does it mean it doesn't work on my device?

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions, Android runs `fstrim` with a daily schedule, provided that the conditions meet. Or it should run on a reboot if not run for 3+ days. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213985/218526) for details.

However if you want to do `TRIM` manually, use Android's commandline tool **`sm fstrim`**. Previously this was `vdc fstrim dotrim` but added to Storage Manager in Oreo <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/31d0b7043d9077ad8a0ebfbd6ff2f98621e6f413%5E%21/#F0))</sup> and removed from `vold` in Pie <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/11c2d380a786d9e304416be98881b90b74ff666d))</sup>.

In order to send `FITRIM ioctl` to selected filesystem(s) only, use `fstrim` tool; a busybox applet.

Both commands require root, or `sm fstrim` can be executed from `adb shell`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having lag issues on my N7 2012. After doing some research I was lead to [Forever Gone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kovit.p.forevergone).

This app has been used to overwrite the free space on the device so that it can be more efficiently used. Until 4.3 is released for you device I would give this a try to see if it helps with performance. It sure helped my N7.

Comment: Funny that when I can't install it on my device since it is registered as a Samsung gt9xxx, but it was ok for my original firmware. Anyway, could you kindly recommend a similar App?

Comment: I am not aware of any other app that does this. If you are on a custom firmware (rooted & rom'd) you can edit a file with the device information to mimic a supported device in order to convince the Play store to let you install it.