# How can I know if fstrim was run when I put my phone on charging over night?

Tags: file-system, logging

Is there any logging where I can confirm if `fstrim` was run when I put my phone on charging over night?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ***charging, idle device over night*** is not the only way to run `fstrim`, there are other ways, too.

Quoting from this [old article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices) about scheduled `fstrim` on Android:

> The Android framework will send out a “start idle maintenance window” event that the MountService listens for, and then invokes vold to fstrim filesystems when a few conditions have been met – the device hasn’t been touched for over an hour, no idle maintenance window event has been sent in 24 hours, and the device is either off-charger with 80% battery or on-charger with 30% battery.

But `IdleMaintenanceService` was removed in Lollipop, things have changed. On Pie, scheduled `fstrim` is triggered from `StorageManagerService` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#739))</sup> to `MountService` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/MountServiceIdler.java#98))</sup>:

> if the device is alive at ***midnight + idle***, fstrim gets run at the next available ***charging + idle*** time

<sup>* ([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#535))</sup>
Mount service calls `StorageManager` which in turn calls `Vold` to do `fstrim`.

If the schedule is being missed because the conditions aren't met and `fstrim` has not run for the last **3 days** <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#9213))</sup>, it will be forced during device startup if the device is restarted. `SystemServer` <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#1027))</sup>, `PackageManager` <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#8929))</sup>, `StorageManager` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#953))</sup> and `Vold` <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/VoldNativeService.cpp#470))</sup> are involved.

In each case, the file `/data/system/last-fstrim` <sup>([9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#541))</sup> (since Lollipop) gets updated <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#581))</sup>, so you can check its timestamp (**requires root**) to find out when `fstrim` was last run.

If you want to do `TRIM` manually, use Android's commandline tool **`sm fstrim` (requires root or `adb shell`**). Previously this was `vdc fstrim dotrim` but added to Storage Manager in Oreo <sup>([11](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/31d0b7043d9077ad8a0ebfbd6ff2f98621e6f413%5E%21/#F0))</sup> and removed from `vold` in Pie <sup>([12](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/11c2d380a786d9e304416be98881b90b74ff666d))</sup>.

In order to send `FITRIM ioctl` to selected filesystem(s) only, use the `fstrim` tool (**requires root**); a BusyBox applet.

---

***What if you don't have root?***
And you suspect that the scheduled `fstrim` is being missed for 3+ days, restart the device, `fstrim` will be forced (since Lollipop 5.1 <sup>([13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#286))</sup>). Simple.

Apps can't `TRIM` without root; see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213987/218526).

---

**PS: HOW OFTEN TRIM SHOULD BE RUN?**

Flash memory (including SSDs, eMMCs, SD Cards, USB sticks etc.) has a limited number of Program/Erase (P/E) cycles before it dies. But unlike HDDs, data can't be just overwritten on flash memory, it has to be erased first, which is achieved through garbage collection (GC).

Now if we do too much `fstrim`, this will cause frequent GC in the background consuming precious `P/E` cycles and hence reducing life. If we don't do `fstrim` at all, there could be unnecessary GC (of already deleted data), plus the write operations will get too slow with time because erasure will have to be performed before overwriting data, which has significantly higher latency compared to the program operation.

So we need a balance between both.

Also there are other factors e.g. whether eMMC controller supports over provisioning, how effective it is in background GC scheduling, wear-leveling and managing write amplification etc.

So unless you have the data sheet of your phone's eMMC and you are sure what you are doing, it's better to leave the `fstrim` to the OS. On PCs <sup>([14](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html))</sup>:

> Running fstrim frequently, or even using `mount -o discard`, might negatively affect the lifetime of poor-quality SSD devices.  For most desktop and server systems a sufficient trimming frequency is ***once a week***.

But this may vary depending on the situation.

**RELATED:**

- [Coding for SSDs](https://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/)
- [Why is TRIM not supported on encrypted “/data” partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214209/218526)

Comment: I have a question. I understand that I shouldn't run trim too often but can "sm trim" work without root through adb?

Comment: Yes, because shell has MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS privileged permission granted by default, so must work without root. But there could possibly be other issues like a bad SELinux policy may not allow this. Also TRIM on encrypted `/data` partition is tricky.

Comment: Is there a way for non-root users to find out when TRIM was last run? I'm on a Pixel 6 Pro running GrapheneOS, if that makes things easier.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun you may find traces in `logcat`, `dumpsys`, `dropbox` etc. I've never tried though.